# having an conditionless error in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Currently I am trying to execute this query. but getting an error. Please identify the error in this query. I am getting an error as I try to execute it. Conditionless error and hard date (something like that). I want to extract whole data from my db with these conditions.".

```
 select

dilbo.warehouse_id
, count(distinct dilbo.mamc)
, sum(dilbo.on_hand_quantity)
, dilbo.inventory_group_id
, to_char(dilbo.snapshot_day, 'MM')
, to_char(dilbo.snapshot_day, 'DD')


,CASE WHEN 
p.PKG_WEIGHT*DECODE(p.PKG_WEIGHT_U, 'pounds', 0.45359, 1.0) > 11.2 
OR GREATEST(p.PKG_LENGTH*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0),p.PKG_Width*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0),p.PKG_Height*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0)) > 60.1
OR p.PKG_LENGTH*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0)+p.PKG_Width*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0)+p.PKG_Height*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0)-GREATEST(p.PKG_LENGTH*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0),p.PKG_Width*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0),p.PKG_Height*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0))-LEAST(p.PKG_LENGTH*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0),p.PKG_Width*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0),p.PKG_Height*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0)) > 30.0 
OR LEAST(p.PKG_LENGTH*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0),p.PKG_Width*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0),p.PKG_Height*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0)) > 31.2 
THEN CASE 
WHEN p.IS_WHITE_GLOVE_REQUIRED = 'Y' 
THEN 'HB' 
ELSE 'NS' END 
ELSE 'S' 
END AS Sort

,CASE WHEN 
p.PKG_WEIGHT*DECODE(p.PKG_WEIGHT_U, 'pounds', 0.45359, 1.0) > 60.1
OR GREATEST(p.PKG_LENGTH*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0),p.PKG_Width*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0),p.PKG_Height*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0)) > 59 
OR p.PKG_LENGTH*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0)+p.PKG_Width*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0)+p.PKG_Height*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0)-GREATEST(p.PKG_LENGTH*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0),p.PKG_Width*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0),p.PKG_Height*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0))-LEAST(p.PKG_LENGTH*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0),p.PKG_Width*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0),p.PKG_Height*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0)) > 59.0 
OR LEAST(p.PKG_LENGTH*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0),p.PKG_Width*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0),p.PKG_Height*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0)) > 44.89 
THEN 'NonX' 
ELSE 'XE'
END as SubSort



from d_owner dilbo, d_items p, d_mamcs dmp

where
dilbo.region_id = 2
and dilbo.warehouse_id = 'STR1'
and dilbo.snapshot_day between to_date('20120701', 'YYYYMMDD') and to_date('20130205', 'YYYYDDMM')
and dilbo.mamc = p.mamc
and to_char(dilbo.snapshot_day, 'DD') in ('28', '30', '31')
and dilbo.mamc = dmp.mamc

group by
dilbo.warehouse_id
, dilbo.inventory_group_id
, to_char(dilbo.snapshot_day, 'MM')
, to_char(dilbo.snapshot_day, 'DD')



,CASE WHEN 
p.PKG_WEIGHT*DECODE(p.PKG_WEIGHT_U, 'pounds', 0.45359, 1.0) > 11.2  
OR GREATEST(p.PKG_LENGTH*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0),p.PKG_Width*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0),p.PKG_Height*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0)) > 59 
OR p.PKG_LENGTH*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0)+p.PKG_Width*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0)+p.PKG_Height*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0)-GREATEST(p.PKG_LENGTH*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0),p.PKG_Width*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0),p.PKG_Height*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0))-LEAST(p.PKG_LENGTH*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0),p.PKG_Width*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0),p.PKG_Height*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0)) > 59 
OR LEAST(p.PKG_LENGTH*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0),p.PKG_Width*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0),p.PKG_Height*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0)) > 44 
THEN CASE 
WHEN p.IS_REQUIRED = 'Y' 
THEN 'ASP' 
ELSE 'CD' END 
ELSE 'D' 
END 

,CASE WHEN 
p.PKG_WEIGHT*DECODE(p.PKG_WEIGHT_U, 'pounds', 0.45359, 1.0) > 11.2 
OR GREATEST(p.PKG_LENGTH*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0),p.PKG_Width*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0),p.PKG_Height*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0)) > 60
OR p.PKG_LENGTH*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0)+p.PKG_Width*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0)+p.PKG_Height*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0)-GREATEST(p.PKG_LENGTH*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0),p.PKG_Width*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0),p.PKG_Height*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0))-LEAST(p.PKG_LENGTH*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0),p.PKG_Width*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0),p.PKG_Height*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0)) > 30 
OR LEAST(p.PKG_LENGTH*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0),p.PKG_Width*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0),p.PKG_Height*DECODE(p.PKG_DIM_U, 'inches', 2.54, 1.0)) > 31.0 
THEN 'NonX' 
ELSE 'XE'
END
```

Comment: To trouble shoot, commment out all the fields except dilbo.warehouse_id in your select and group by clauses.  Run the query.  If successful, start adding fields 1 by 1 until you find the cause of the error.  Otherwise, start commenting out parts of your where and from clause as well.

Comment: And what exactly is the error?

Answer (score 1):

The list of columns in the GROUP BY clause has to match *exactly* the list of non-aggregate columns in the SELECT.

I can see that some of the values in the second-to-last CASE statement in the GROUP BY are not exactly the same as the ones in the SELECT.

In the select you have

`WHEN p.IS_WHITE_GLOVE_REQUIRED = 'Y' 
THEN 'HB' 
ELSE 'NS' END 
ELSE 'S'`

In the GROUP BY you have:

`WHEN p.IS_REQUIRED = 'Y' 
THEN 'ASP' 
ELSE 'CD' END 
ELSE 'D'`

Comment: Ohh, sry! but, yes even after correcting these. The  same problem "Conditionless joins detected"

Comment: I mean get rid of *everything* you have in the group by, and copy there what you have in the SELECT - excluding the aggregate columns, of course. I pointed out an example of differences but I'm sure there are more.